# Storing data related to facebook user in database

Tags: php, facebook, validation, security, facebook-graph-api

What I'm trying to do is implement a "log in with Facebook button" on my site. I think I have understood most of the Facebook JS API, yet I am not certain of how I *securely* can tie information in my own databases up against a Facebook user. My current theory is:
1. Register Facebook's UID for the user in database for further reference.
2. Tie all further information from the user (the infromation inputted by the user in the application) up to the user ID after verifying the Facebook access token (in the backend), to prevent user from adding/removing information on behalf of another user.
3. When the user makes a query for information, you verify the access token issued by the JS API in your backend up against Facebook's APIs before returning any information related to the user, to prevent the user from spoofing his own ID

Side note: Not sure if Stack Overflow is the correct place to post this question.I know that there is an enormous number of sub sections on Stack Exchange. If this isn't the place then let me know :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented a login with Facebook module in my recent node project. When the user logs into Facebook successfully, it usually returns a unique Facebook ID (along with a lot of other data). You could then create a relation table in your database that relates the unique Facebook ID with a special user ID for your site.

If you have facebook info you are going to need frequently like profile image... I would grab the url every time and store it in a session variable when the user logs in simply because it can change.

Comment: Oh? So the Facebook Graph API has an object containing an ID that is Unique to the user on that specific application?

Comment: @AlexanderHansen Yes

Comment: @AlexanderHansen if this worked for you then please mark as correct for future users.